# Separator between strings from JSON

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I am trying to save text file with string values from JSON array (Pandas library), but I am strugling to separate them with comma sign. What I want achieve is this:

```
0, 0, 0
1,    0,   5
2,    0,  10
3,    0,  15
4,    5,   0
5,   10,   0
6,   15,   0
7,   15,   5
8,   15,  10
9,   15,  15
10,  10,  15
11,   5,  15
```

while saving the string output to file gives me this (0 and 1 are numbers of columns, which I don't want in file):

```
0     1
0    0   0
1    0   5
2    0  10
3    0  15
4    5   0
5   10   0
6   15   0
7   15   5
8   15  10
9   15  15
10  10  15
11   5  15
```

This is my code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

points = np.array([(0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 5.0), (0.0, 10.0), (0.0, 15.0), (5.0, 0.0), (10.0, 0.0), (15.0, 0.0), (15.0, 5.0), (15.0, 10.0), (15.0, 15.0), (10.0, 15.0), (5.0, 15.0)])

df = pd.DataFrame(points)
df.to_json('data.json')

y = pd.read_json(r'data.json')

file = open("result.inp", "w")

file.write(str(y))
file.close()
```

Some advices?

Comment: Can you explain your question a bit more? _I am trying to save text file with string values from JSON array (Pandas library)_ Doesn't make much sense to me. What does your actual code look like? Why have a column of tuples in a DataFrame? Why JSON, for that data?

Comment: try setting the orient in the `df.to_json` e.g `df.to_json('file.json',orient='columns')`

Comment: Why don't you just write points directly? Why go to json and cone back?

Answer (score 0):

A little ugly, but this will work.

```
strY = str(y).replace('     ','0, ').replace('    ',', ').replace('   ',', ').replace('  ',', '))
file.write(strY)
```

Comment: thanks, that works, but what if I want to remove 1st line (0 1)?

Answer (score 0):

make a change in the last second line.

```
file.write(str(y.to_csv(sep=',')))
```

Comment: yep, that worked, now I have results separated by comma, but still want to get rid of this 1st row (0 1) - do you have any idea?

Comment: give the argument `header = False`  in the `.to_csv() function`. Then the code be like `file.write(str(y.to_csv(sep=',', header= False)))` which will ignore writing header to file. You can refer to link for [pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) for API reference.